# Confused of one step of proofing convexity of a function related to LP

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, convexity-inequality

I read about this question about proving that the function of the optimal value of an LP is concave.
[Proof that $\xi^*(b)$ is concave for arbitrary b in a linear program](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3569984/proof-that-xib-is-concave-for-arbitrary-b-in-a-linear-program)

[@Max](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/654677/max) who asked this question posted his proof as an answer underneath. But there's one step that doesn't make sense to me.

> Perturb b1 to $tb_1+(1−t)b_2$. Then $y_1$ remains dual feasible, and $(tb_1+(1−t)b_2)^Ty_1$ provides a lower bound for the optimal objective value of this new problem.

My question is why does $(tb_1+(1−t)b_2)^Ty_1$ provides a lower bound to $\xi^*(tb_1+(1−t)b_2)$? Since $\xi^*(b)$ is a maximization problem, by weak duality it should provide an upper bound to $\xi^*(tb_1+(1−t)b_2)$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be an upper bound? In any case, the result holds with the following $\xi^*(tb_1+(1-t)b_2) = (tb_1+(1-t)b_2)^Ty^* = tb_1^Ty^*+(1-t)b_2^Ty^* \geq tb_1^Ty_1^*+(1-t)b_2^Ty_2^* = t\xi^*(b_1)+(1-t)\xi^*(b_2)$ with $y^*$, $y_1^*$ and $y_2^*$ the optimal duals at $tb_1+(1-t)b_2$, $b_1$ and $b_2$.. This uses strong duality tough and not only weak duality.